# Regular expressions and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexp:

```
var re = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classname + "(\\s|$)");
```

I understand **\s** is a white-space character; the caret means "beginning with". What I don't understand is the pipe character here...

How does the expression above translate into English?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `(^|\s)`  is an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). It means "either the start of the string or a whitespace character". Similarly `(\s|$)` means "either the end of the string or a whitespace character".

This sort of regular expression is useful for finding a word in a space separated list where there is no space at the start or end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fast and relevant reply Mark!

Answer (score 1):

The `|` symbol in javascript regex means "`or`".

You can check out a helpful list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions This was listed on the fabulous javascript regex tester site **regexpal.com**

Answer (score 1):

The `|` means or so -

> Match start of the line (^) or a whitespace character
>
> Match value of `classname` variable
>
> Match  whitespace character or end of line ($)